# Canvas break for firefox desktop browser, for chrome desktop works fine only if cookies are loaded

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cookies, cpanel

I have the following code in this [link](https://jsbin.com/xapocacemo/1/edit?html,css,js,output). Which should let the user draw with the mouse on the canvas. If I access on the cpanel and load the var img at the following link it works

```
var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://domenicoromeo.xyz:2083/cpsess8711280373/viewer/home%2fuxmew1flgnpk%2fdomenicoromeo/brush.png';
```

I noticed that I have a lot of [cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FePEZ.png) on chrome and the application works, but as soon as I clear the cookies it doesn't let me draw more because it is not able to reload the same amount of cookies, and it shows me that the canvas is broke [broke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APbPs.png)

If I try to use firefox it doesn't work at all giving error like

```
[Show/hide message details.] NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: index.js:80
draw/el.onmousemove
http://localhost:63342/website/index.js:80:13
```

How am I suppose to make it stabile everywhere, all the platform/browsers? I have looked everywhere

Comment: You must wait for your images have loaded before doing anything with it + http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ for when it *works* in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that as soon as you clear the cookies, then there is no way for the server to recognise who you are... you are clearing all session identifiers or, in other terms, logging out.